# Replacing fragment wrong order when not using addToBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a menu where the user can click on different buttons and swap between different bottom bars.

When a user clicks button1 following happens:

```
setFragment(R.id.bottom_bar_container, new FooBottomBar());
```

When they click button2 it will call:

```
setFragment(R.id.bottom_bar_container, new BarBottomBar());
```

Heres the setFragment method:

```
private void setFragment(int layout, Fragment newFragment) {
    String tag = newFragment.getClass().getCanonicalName();

    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = newFragment;
    }

    Log.d("Tag", "Replacing with " + tag);

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(layout, fragment, tag)
            .commit();
}
```

This works overall well but if user spam clicks on both buttons something interesting can happen.

Logcat:

```
Tag: Replacing with com.example.FooBottomBar
Tag: Replacing with com.example.BarBottomBar
```

But in the UI I can see `FooBottomBar` even though the last replacement was `BarBottomBar`.

I found that if I add `addToBackStack(null)` the problem goes away but I don't want to have this on the back stack.

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(layout, fragment, tag)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

I would like to know the reason for this issue and if there's any solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` with `commitNow()` instead.

```
getChildFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(layout, fragment, tag)
        .commitNow();
```